# Publish PowershellCore Binary Module

Tags: .net-core, powershell-core

I'm working on a binary module for PowerShellCore. I've published the module to the PowershellGallery. When I'm trying to test my module I get the following error:

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.                                                                                                                                                                               
At /Users/janbaarssen/Projects/MFA/DevOps/PowerShell/AcmeCoreModule/src/Test-Application.ps1:5 char:1                                                                                 
+ Import-Module -Name AcmeCoreModule                                                                                                                                                  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                  
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Unfortunate I wasn't able to find anything on this topic. I referenced the correct NuGet package but it is still not working.

This are my NuGet packages:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net472'">
    <PackageReference Include="Certes" Version="2.3.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NewtonSoft.JSON" Version="11.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.5.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="6.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What can I do to make this work. At so far I can't find anything on this topic. The module will have to work on MacOS and Windows.